# SharePoint 2010 Meeting Workspace Permission Denied

Tags: 2010, meeting-workspace

Well, I have just created a Basic Meeting Workspace and have attached a recurrent meeting.
Once I've entered the site, sometimes (it's a random behavior 3/4 or 1/2 of the times) it just goes blank with the date of the opened meeting on it, something like:

> **Date:** 12/16/2014 **Time:** 4:00 PM -‎ 5:00 PM

and on the Console, you can find something like:

> SCRIPT70: Permission denied
>
> jquery-1.7.2.js?rev=r2k%2Fmup9rjb7O%2B9Mm25W%2Bw%3D%3D, line 6081 character 6

I've tried EVERYTHING that I've found so far:
Yes, the trick on the master page, verifying that the references below exist

> ```
> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Meetings" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Meetings" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
> <Meetings:PropertyBag runat="server"/>
> ```

Yes, changing the reference below, to the top of the masterpage

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><br/><br/>
> ```

and I got no clue on how to solve this issue, anyone?